# Why is the position of the centre of mass of the system changing in y direction if there is force only in the x direction?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

[image]

I know that a tension force might act within the body, but it is an internal force and must not change the position of centre of mass of the system. The net force in the vertical(mg+normal) is always zero, and only force acting on it is friction in x-direction.
But at close inspection we see that Centre of mass changes its position in y-direction despite no initial momentum or force in that direction? why so?

Comment: The net force in the vertical direction is not zero.  I won't say more to give you time to digest that fact.

Comment: Why do you assume that N=mg on this set up? When is that assumption valid, always? Is it actually an assumption, or rather, a conclusion in the cases when it is true?.

Comment: @garyp According to my understanding, let us say after a time t, the system consists of the rolled part and unrolled part. The rolled part is at rest on the ground so its weight must be balanced by a normal force, now for the unrolled part, you can imagine it to be a rigid cylinder performing pure rolling about the point of contact with the ground, the normal should balance this weight as it is a rigid body(inextensible)? hence the net force in vertical must be zero. Am i missing something?

Comment: Your rolling cylinder example is essentially a static situation.  Therefore it does not apply to the case at hand.

Comment: @garyp how is this different? pls can you explain.